# png file not displaying

Tags: iis, png

i have a few png files in my asp.net 3.5 web app.  the images displaying correctly in dev; however, when i load the app on the server, the png files do not display.  i'm using w2k8 and iis.  when i server another image file from same directory (jpg), it works.  is there something i am missing with png files?

Comment: Is there a MIME type set up for PNG? Does the file have the correct permissions? and if you navigate directly to the file /file.png what error do you get?

Comment: Is the website public? If so, please post a link to the PNG that cannot be shown so that we can see if the HTTP headers give any detail about the issue.

Comment: @Bernhard Hofmann : Good suggestion

Comment: interesting - i get a 401.3 when browsing to the file directly on the server with ie.  there is a mime type for png.  everyone has read access to the file, however owner-creator has no access to the file - when i try to change the acl, it doesn't take the changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a permissions problem. Have you checked the permissions on one of the PNG files to be certain that they can be read by EVERYONE?

If you can access the server directly, can you see the images if you use a browser on the server and visit the local site? http://localhost/

Can you try view the PNG directly by URL from your browser? By that I mean entering the full URL to the PNG itself rather than the page that is showing the PNG. For example http://sstatic.net/so/img/logo.png

Comment: it looks like everyone has read access.  when i try to view the file in IE, it tries to download it instead of display it.  i think that is the big clue - but i don't know what to do about it

Comment: ok - the file was encrypted...  not sure why a png is encrypted, but removing encryption fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Very late but maybe not a wrong solution:
If you rename a .jpg to .png it won't show in Microsoft's browsers.
If you save the file again in Paint for example, it will change the mime-type or file-headers thus it will load after that change.

You can test this pretty easily:

- Rename a .jpg file to .png
- Load the page : The image is broken
- Save the file as .png now
- Load the page : The image will load now

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused by IIS not having the Mime Types/Static Content option installed.  This can be installed as follows (taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/42191613/1551685):-

*...if you're on a non-server OS like Windows 8, do a search on the start page for "Turn Windows features on or off" and enable Internet Information Services -> World Wide Web Services -> Common HTTP Features -> Static Content"*

(Why this isn't installed by default is anyone's guess).