# CF10 developer on IIS7.5 / WIN7 - CFM files run ok - but can't see .GIFs

Tags: coldfusion, iis-7.5, coldfusion-10

Can anyone help with this strange problem.

I have just installed CF10 developer on Win7 which is using IIS7.5.

Installation went smooth, and can browse .cfm files no problem and connect to datasources no problem .. BUT: even though I can browse all my local cf sites, none of the sites will display images or styles for external .CSS files.

So, I get the site, content from the database, and all the functionality of cfm files being parsed OK, but no styles and no images.

If I browse directly (pasting the filepath in the browser) to one of the images I get a 404 error - file not found - even though the .gif file does indeed exist in the directory.

So, basically, I can run CFM files, and browse a local site built in coldfusion, but none of the images or externally referenced css files will be "found" by the browser/IIS.

Can anyone help?
Thanks in advance if someone can..

Comment: What happens if you create an html file in the same directory and use an img tag?

Comment: What is the file structure of your environment, including: web root, CF root, any virtual directories, and within those where the CF files that are working, and non-CF files that aren't working. What happens if you create another website on IIS - ignoring CF completely - and browse to HTML, CSSS and GIF files?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like an issue with those mimetypes, please see the following for information on installing the static content role to IIS and enabling those mimetypes to be served.

[No Mime Types Option in IIS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6374419/no-mime-types-option-in-iis-7)

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to enable static content in IIS 7.

Had two occurrences of this problem lately.

See here:

http://weblogs.asp.net/anasghanem/archive/2008/05/23/don-t-forget-to-check-quot-static-content-service-quot-in-iis7-installation.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting the IIS server. Close all browsers and restart.

Answer (score 0):

You need to determine if it is a CF issue or an IIS issue. Try the following:

- Check to see if this is an issue with images not being served vs broken paths to the images. There may be CFML code that is creating links to invalid locations.
- If the locations are valid then it would be an issue with IIS not server image files.
- Also check to see if there is a similar issue with JPEG and PNG files. If JPEGs and PNGs show up, this suggests an IIS issue.
- Also try creating a simple HTML page that has an image on it. If it has an image on it, this suggests a CF issue