# Stylesheet not loaded because of MIME type

Tags: html, css, gulp, mime-types, browser-sync

I'm working on a website that uses [Gulp.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gulp.js) to compile and browser sync to keep the browser synchronised with my changes.

The Gulp.js task compiles everything properly, but on the website, I'm unable to see any style, and the console shows this error message:

> Refused to apply style from
> 'http://localhost:3000/assets/styles/custom-style.css' because its
> MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and
> strict MIME checking is enabled.

Now, I don't really understand why this happens.

The HTML includes the file like this (which I am pretty sure is correct):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/styles/custom-style.css"/>
```

And the style sheet is a merge between [Bootstrap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_%28front-end_framework%29) and [Font Awesome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Font_Awesome) styles for now (nothing custom yet).

The path is correct as well, as this is the folder structure:

```
index.html
assets
|-styles
  |-custom-style.css
```

But I keep getting the error.

What could it be? Is this something (maybe a setting?) for gulp/browsersync maybe?

Comment: It happens when you set an incorrect URL to the file or when your server isn't configured properly. In the result, the browser DOESN'T get the stylesheet, but it gets some HTML with 404 status and with the "Content-Type" header. Since the browser gets something from the server, it doesn't tell you there is no reply, but it tells you the MIME type of the file is incorrect. The fastest way to check it is just to try to open the file directly `http://localhost:3000/assets/styles/custom-style.css` in a new tab.

Comment: In the currently 83 answers (incl. deleted), there are a lot of redundant answers (repeating previous answers).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Refused to execute script, strict MIME type checking is enabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40574159/refused-to-execute-script-strict-mime-type-checking-is-enabled)

Answer (score 191, accepted):

The issue, I think, was with a CSS library starting with comments.

While in development, I do not minify files and I don't remove comments. This meant that the stylesheet started with some comments, causing it to be seen as something different from CSS.

Removing the library and putting it into a vendor file (which is ALWAYS minified without comments) solved the issue.

Again, I'm not 100% sure this is a fix, but it's still a win for me as it works as expected now.

Comment: In my case my css starts with comments, not causing any issues. The missing /css/ on the front of the path, where css/ was a folder at the root of the source tree, was my issue.

Comment: Yes, I don't have comments in one file and another has comments.  Both have the same error.

Answer (score 307):

For Node.js applications, check your configuration:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Notice that `/public` does not have a forward slash at the end, so you will need to include it in your href option of your HTML:

```
href="/css/style.css">
```

If you did include a forward slash (`/public/`) then you can just do `href="css/style.css"`.

Comment: This was my issue, even for javascript front end instead of Node backend... Starting with /css, the files were found. The error message is strangely bogus, implying it DID find the file and checked its type and found it to be wrong.

Comment: Isn't the different `href`s a matter of relative vs absolute URIs? Without a leading slash is relative to the page URL; with a leading slash is relative to the root (domain and port). As well as I remember in the middle of the night, anyway. I'm not too familiar with the specifics of `express.static()`, but I don't believe a trailing slash would make a difference? And if it does, what is the reason?

Answer (score 196):

In most cases, this could be simply the **CSS file path is wrong**. So the web server returns `status: 404` with some `Not Found` content payload of `html` type.

The browser follows this (wrong) path from `<link rel="stylesheet" ...>` tag with the intention of applying CSS styles. But the returned content type contradicts so that it logs an error.

[image]

Comment: another way to troubleshoot, paste the url you're getting this error on into another tab, if you're not seeing CSS, this is likely the issue

Answer (score 149):

This error can also come up when you're not referring to your CSS file properly.

For example, if your link tag is

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
```

but your CSS file is named `style.css` (without the second s) then there is a good chance that you will see this error.

Comment: To add to this answer, be sure gulp actually found the css file and piped it into your dist. Whenever I get this error, it is because I screwed up my path to the css files somehow and it just doesn't exist in the build directory.

Answer (score 75):

I had this error for a Bootstrap template.

```html
<link href="starter-template.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Then I removed the `rel="stylesheet"` from the link, i.e.:

```html
<link href="starter-template.css">
```

And everything works fine. Try this if you are using Bootstrap templates.

Comment: According to the [Living Standard (4.2.4)](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#attr-link-rel), *"A link element must have either a rel attribute or an itemprop attribute, but not both."* So, removing the `rel` attribute just removes the functionality of including a stylesheet.

Comment: This worked for me too on bootstrap. Seems to stem from a different issue than what @nick was facing, but both issues return the same MIME error on console.

Answer (score 73):

I have changed my `href` to `src`. So from this:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/photoswipe.css">
```

to this:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" src="dist/photoswipe.css">
```

It worked. I don't know why, but it did the job.

Comment: Same with me. Worked only this solution

Comment: but it should be href  https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_link.asp

Comment: This fixed the issue for me in Safari 17.1.

Answer (score 54):

Make a folder just below/above the style.css file as per the Angular structure and provide a link like `<link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`.

[image]

Comment: Why does this work? The error states that "text/html" is not a supported MIME type.

Comment: In my case the error went away, the css styles, however, are not applied.. :/

Comment: I did spend aome more time reading about this issue and changing the type of a css file ibto something else can cause serious issues, like css being read as html by the server

Comment: In AngularDart, the root for index.html is the 'web' folder not the project main folder. So all the css files must be inside the web folder. Like this "[projectfolder]\web\[yourcssfileshere]". So if you try to import a css file located outside the web folder it will not be found.

Answer (score 32):

Comments in your file will trip this. **Some minifiers will not remove comments.**

#### Also

If you use [Node.js](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js) and set your static files using `express` such as:

```javascript
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

You need to properly address the files.

In my case both were the issue, so I prefixed my CSS links with "/css/styles.css".

Example:

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href='/css/styles.css">
```

This solution is perfect as the path is the main issue for CSS not getting rendering

Answer (score 30):

In addition to using:

```html
<base href="/">
```

Remove the `rel="stylesheet"` part from your CSS links:

```html
<link type="text/css" href="assets/styles/custom-style.css"/>
```

Comment: I removed class="js-stylesheet" and it works like magic :)

Comment: Anyone know why it  is not working with class="js-stylesheet" ?

Comment: would love to know the lore behind this causing an issue

Answer (score 23):

The problem is that if you have a relative path, and you navigate to a nested page, that would resolve to the wrong path:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href='./index.css'>
```

so the simple solution was to remove the `.` since mine is a [single-page application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application).

Like this:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href='/index.css'>
```

so it always resolves to `/index.css`

There are a lot of answers to this question but none of them seem to really work. If you remove `rel="stylesheet"` it will stop the errors but won't apply the stylesheets.

The real solution:

Just remove the `.`. It works then.

Comment: Scrolling all this way was worth it! Thank you for this comment!

Answer (score 22):

I simply referenced the CSS file (an Angular theme in my case) in the *styles* section of my Angular 6 build configuration in angular.json:

[image]

This does not answer the question, but it might be a suitable workaround, as it was for me.

Answer (score 19):

I know it might be out of context but linking a non existed file might cause this issue as it happened to me before.

```
<!-- bootstrap grid -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/bootstrap-grid.css" />
```

If this file does not exist you will face that issue.

Answer (score 18):

As mentioned solutions in this post, some of the solutions worked for me, but CSS does not apply on the page.

Simply, I just moved the "css" directory into the "Assest/" directory and everything works fine.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/site.css" >
```

Answer (score 17):

I got the same issue and then I checked that I wrote:

`<base href="./">` in index.html

Then I changed to

```
<base href="/">
```

And then it worked fine.

Answer (score 16):

Also for others using Angular-CLI and publishing to a sub-folder on the webserver, check this answer:

When you're deploying to a non-root path within a domain, you'll need to manually update the `<base href="/">` tag in your `dist/index.html.`

In this case, you will need to update to `<base href="/sub-folder/">`

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1080

Answer (score 13):

I had this problem with a site I knew worked online when I moved it to localhost and [PhpStorm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhpStorm).

This worked fine online:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/additional.css">
```

But for [localhost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost) I needed to get rid of the slash:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/additional.css">
```

So I am reinforcing a few answers provided here already - it is likely to be a path or spelling mistake rather than any complicated server setup problem. The error in the console is a red herring; the network tab needs to be checked for the 404 first.

Among the answers provided here are a few solutions that are not correct. The addition of `type="text/html"` or changing `href` to `src` is not the answer.

If you want to have all of the attributes so it validates on the pickiest of validators and your IDE then the media value should be provided and the `rel` should be `stylesheet`, e.g.:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/additional.css" type="text/css" media="all">
```

Answer (score 10):

I have had the same problem.

If your project's structure is like the following tree:

```
index.html
assets
|-styles
  |-custom-style.css
server
  |- server.js
```

I recommend to add the following piece of code in `server.js`:

```
var path = require('path')
var express = require('express')
var app = express()

app.use('/assets', express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../assets")));
```

**Note:** Path is a built-in Node.js module, so it doesn't need to install this package via npm.

Answer (score 9):

You can open the Google Chrome tools, select the network tab, reload your page and find the file request of the CSS and look for what it have inside the file.

Maybe you did something wrong when you merged the two libraries in your file, including some characters or headers not properly for CSS?

Comment: unfortunately i did try it but it is not really helping, the request fails instantly and it only has the request url (which is correct)

Answer (score 9):

At times, this happens when the CSS file is not found. It's worth checking your base URL / path to the file.

Comment: This is already covered in previous answers.

Answer (score 8):

Adding to a long list of answers, this issue also happened to me because I did not realize the path was wrong from a browser-sync point of view.

Given this simple folder structure:

```
package.json
app
  |-index.html
  |-styles
          |-style.css
```

The `href` attribute inside `<link>` in file *index.html* has to be `app/styles/style.css` and not `styles/style.css`.

Answer (score 8):

In case you are using [Express.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Express.js) without any JavaScript code, try with:

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

As an example, my CSS file is at `public/stylesheets/app.css`.

Answer (score 7):

For a Node.js application, just use this after importing all the required modules in your server file:

```
app.use(express.static("."));
```

- express.static built-in middleware function in Express and this in your .html file: <`link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">`

Answer (score 7):

How I solved this.
For Node.js applications, you need to set your `**public**` folder configuration.

```
// Express js
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Otherwise, you need to do like  `href="public/css/style.css".`

```
<link href="public/assets/css/custom.css">
<script src="public/assets/js/scripts.js"></script>
```

> Note: It will work for `http://localhost:3000/public/assets/css/custom.css`. But couldn't work after build. You need to set `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));` for Express

Answer (score 6):

I was working with the React application and also had this error which led me here. This is what helped me.

Instead of adding `<link>` to the `index.html`, I added an `import` to the component where I need to use this style sheet:

```
import 'path/to/stylesheet.css';
```

Answer (score 6):

By going into my browsers console → *Network* → *style.css* ...clicked on it and it showed "cannot get /path/to/my/CSS", this told me my link was wrong.
I changed that to the path of my CSS file.

The original path before change was *localhost:3000/Example/public/style.css*. Changing it to *localhost:3000/style.css* solved it.

If you are serving the file from app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public"))); or app.use(express.static("public")); your server would pass "that folder" to the browser so adding a "/yourCssName.css" link in your browser solves it

By adding other routes in your browser CSS link, you'd be telling the browser to search for the css in route specified.

In summary: Check where your browser CSS link points to.

Answer (score 5):

**This is specific to TypeScript and Express.js**

I <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>'d "TypeScript" and ".ts" and found nothing in these answers, so I'll add my solution here, since it was caused by (my inexperience with) TypeScript, and the solutions I've read don't explicit solve this particular issue.

The problem was that TypeScript was compiling my `app.ts` file into a JavaScript file in my project's `dist` directory, `dist/app.js`.

Here's my directory structure. See if you can spot the problem:

```
.
├── app.ts
├── dist
│   ├── app.js
│   ├── app.js.map
│   └── js
│       ├── dbclient.js
│       ├── dbclient.js.map
│       ├── mutators.js
│       └── mutators.js.map
├── public
│   ├── css
│   │   └── styles.css
├── tsconfig.json
├── tslint.json
└── views
    ├── index.hbs
    └── results.hbs
```

My problem is that in `app.ts`, I was telling express to set my public directory as `/public`, which would be a valid path if [Node.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js) actually were running TypeScript. But Node.js is running the compiled JavaScript, `app.js`, which is in the `dist` directory.

So having `app.ts` *pretend* it's `dist/app.js` solved my problem. Thus, I fixed the problem in `app.ts` by changing

```
app.use(e.static(path.join(__dirname, "/public")));
```

to

```
app.use(e.static(path.join(__dirname, "../public")));
```

Answer (score 5):

https://github.com/froala/angular-froala/issues/170#issuecomment-386117678
Found the above solution of adding

```
href="/">
```

Just before the style tag in index.html

[image]

Answer (score 4):

In my case, when I was deploying the package live, I had it out of the public HTML folder. It was for a reason.

But apparently a strict MIME type check has been activated, and I am not too sure if it's on my side or by the company I am hosting with.

But as soon as I moved the styling folder in the same directory as the index.php file I stopped getting the error, and styling was activated perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

If you are setting Styles in JavaScript as:

```
    var cssLink = document.createElement("link");
    cssLink.href = "./content.component.scss";
    cssLink.rel = "stylesheet";

    /*  →  */   cssLink.type = "html/css";
    (iframe as HTMLIFrameElement).contentDocument.head.appendChild(cssLink);
```

Then just change field *cssLint.type* (denoted by the arrow in the above description) to "MIME":

```
   cssLink.type = "MIME";
```

It will help you to get rid of the error.

Answer (score 4):

### Bootstrap styles not loading #3411

### https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3411

1. I installed Bootstrap v. 3.3.7

   ```
   npm install bootstrap --save
   ```
2. Then I added the needed script files to `apps[0].scripts` in the angular-cli.json file:

   ```
   "scripts": [
       "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
   ],

   // And the Bootstrap CSS to the apps[0].styles array

   "styles": [
       "styles.css",
       "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"
   ],
   ```
3. I restarted ng serve

It worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

If the browser can not find a related CSS file, it could give this error.

If you use an Angular application you do not have to use a CSS file path in file *index.html*:

```html
<link href="xxx.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

You could use the related CSS file path in the *styles.css* file.

```
@import "../node_modules/material-design-icons-iconfont/dist/material-design-icons.css";
```

Comment: What is the significance of `-->`?

Comment: @PeterMortensen nothing, just edited code.

Answer (score 4):

It's the path that is wrong.

My path was

```
href="public/css/style.css".  <!-- But it should be href="public/style.css" -->
```

And it didn't work. I tried all other ways, but still it did not work. So I ***copied*** the relative path, changed the backslash to forward slash, and then it started to work.

If you're not sure of the path, right click the *style.css* file, click "Copy Relative Path", and then paste it into

```
  href="public\style.css"
```

You just need to change the backward slash to a forward slash.

```
  href="public/style.css"
```

[image]

Comment: Backslash because it is on Windows (in [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code))? What version of Windows?

Comment: @Peter Mortensen -- mine is Windows 10 Home.

Comment: In my case it was all about path also. There was just no such stylesheet.

Answer (score 3):

One of the main reasons for the issue is the CSS file, which it is trying to load, isn't a valid CSS file.

Causes:

- Invalid MIME type
- Having JavaScript code inside style sheet - (may occur due to incorrect Webpack bundler configuration)

Check the file which you're trying to load is a valid CSS style sheet (get the server URL of the file from the network tab and hit in a new tab and verify).

Useful info for consideration when using <link> inside the body tag.

Though having a `link` tag inside the body is not the standard way to use the tag. But we can use it for page optimization (more information: *[Optimize CSS Delivery](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/OptimizeCSSDelivery)*) / if the business use case demands (when you serve the body of the content and server configured to have to render the HTML page with content provided).

While keeping inside the body tag we have to add the attribute `itemProperty` in the `link` tag like

```html
<body>
    <!-- … -->
      <link itemprop="url" href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Catcher_in_the_Rye" />
    <!-- … -->
</body>
```

For more information on `itemProperty`, have a look in *[Can I use <link> tags in the body of an HTML document?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/55130/can-i-use-link-tags-in-the-body-of-an-html-document)*.

Answer (score 3):

Remove rel="stylesheet" and add type="text/html". So it will look like this -

```html
<link href="styles.css" type="text/html" />
```

Answer (score 3):

This issue happens when you're using a command-line tool for either [React](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/React_(JavaScript_library)) or [Angular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_(web_framework)), so the key is to copy the entire final build from those tools since they initialize their own light servers which confuses your URLs with the back end server you've created...

Take that whole build folder and dump it on the asset folder of your back end server project and reference them from your back end server and not the server which ships with Angular or React. Otherwise, you're using it as the front end from a certain API server.

Answer (score 3):

In my case I had to both make sure that the link was relative and the rel property was after the href property:

```html
<link href="/assets/styles/iframe.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same issue in [EJS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScriptMVC#View) and [Node.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js).

I have set up my view engine's public folder like this:

```javascript
app.use('/public', express.static(process.cwd() + '/public'));

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

And my directory structure was like this

```
public
|
-assets
 |
  --CSS
  |---style.css
```

I was trying to link my `Style.css` in EJS head like this

```html
<link href="/assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

*Adding* the `public` solved the problem (*make sure to check network tab*)

```html
<link href="/public/assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution from [this thread](https://github.com/froala/angular-froala/issues/170) solved my problem:

> Not sure if this will help anyone, but if you are using angular-cli, I fixed this by removing the CSS reference from my index.html and adding it to the angular-cli.json file under the "style" portion.
>   After restarting my webserver I no longer had that issue.

Answer (score 2):

I came across this issue having the same problem adding a custom look and feel to an [Azure B2C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Azure#Identity) user flow. I found that the root that the HTML page referred to was ../oauth/v2 (i.e. the [OAuth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth) server path) rather than the path to my storage bob.

Using the full URL of the pages fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 2):

Check if you have a compression enabled or disabled. If you use it or someone enabled it, then `app.use(express.static(xxx))` won't help. Make sure your server allows for compression.

I started to see the similar error when I added [Brotli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brotli) and Compression Plugins to my [Webpack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webpack). Then your server needs to support this type of content compression too.

If you are using [Express.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Express.js) then the following should help:

`app.use(url, expressStaticGzip(dir, gzipOptions)`

Module is called: *express-static-gzip*

My settings are:

```
const gzipOptions = {
  enableBrotli: true,
  customCompressions: [{
  encodingName: 'deflate',
  fileExtension: 'zz'
 }],
 orderPreference: ['br']
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I almost tried all given solutions. The problem for me was I didn't have any [MIME types option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6374419/no-mime-types-option-in-iis-7) in IIS, that is, I was missing this Windows feature.

[The solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42191613/5772425) for me was:

> "And if you're on a non-server OS like Windows 8 or 10, do a search on the start page for "**Turn Windows features on or off**" and enable: **Internet Information Services -> World Wide Web Services -> Common HTTP Features -> Static Content**"

**Enable IIS Static Content**

[image: Enable IIS Static Content]

Answer (score 2):

Nothing that everyone comments has helped me, the solution has been to fix the routes since from the main page I found the file but when I navigated it disappeared, the correct solution would say to have these things well placed

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I also had the same problem: here is the solution. Don't write **public** in path of the CSS link in your **.html** file. Although your **.css** file present in the public folder.

Example:

**JavaScript file**

```javascript
app.use(express.static("public"));
```

**HTML file**

Use this

```html
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

instead of

```html
<link href="index/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 2):

Add [Express.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Express.js) default static middleware as:

Import express `const express =  require("express")`

Initialize express `const app =  express()`

```javascript
app.use(express.static(__dirname));
```

Then you need to use complete path of `public directory`

For example:

Your file structure inside `public directory`

`public > css > style.css`

Your path will be

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./public/css/style.css"/>
```

Note 1:

You can use any name instead of `public`, i.e., `assets` `myassets` `any other`.

Note 2: your server should be running in the main directory.
If your server is running in a sub directory, then you can come out by using ../

Answer (score 1):

Triple check the name and path of the file. In my case I had something like this content in the target folder:

```
lib
    foobar.bundle.js
    foobr.css
```

And this link:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/foobar.css">
```

I guess that the browser was trying to load the JavaScript file and complaining about its MIME type instead of giving me a file not found error.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error, in Angular. The way I solved it was to put an [ngIf](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf) on my link element, so it didn't appear in the DOM until my dynamic URL was populated.

It may be unrelated to the question a little bit, but I ended up here looking for an answer.

```html
<link *ngIf="cssUrl" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" [href]="sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(cssUrl)">
```

Answer (score 1):

I met this issue.

I refused to apply the style from 'http://m.b2b-v2-pre1.jcloudec.com/mobile-dynamic-load-component-view/resource/js/resource/js/need/layer.css?2.0' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

Changing the path could solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and in my case it was due to the fact that I had manually tried to import (s)CSS files in the HTML file (like we always do with static websites), when in fact the files had to be imported in the entry point JavaScript file used by Webpack.

When the stylesheets were imported into the main JavaScript file, rather than manually written in the HTML, it all worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have an authorization issue with Buddy:

Try these steps:

1. Go to ISS → find your project listed → click on it → Click on *Edit permissions* in the right pane under actions
2. You will see your project properties wizard. Click on Securities
3. Under groups or user names → If you see 'Authenticated users', then you are authorized if not then you have to it.
4. Once you add it (yourself or with the help of your administrator if you work in a company :)), the website will start loading resources.  You may need to restart your project under ISS.

Comment: Who or what is *"Buddy"*? *[RegexBuddy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RegexBuddy)?* Or something else?

Comment: What is *"[ISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISS_(disambiguation))"*? Do you mean *[IIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Information_Services)*?

Answer (score 1):

Yet another reason for this error may be that the CSS file permissions are incorrect. In my case the file was inaccessible because ownership had been changed to the root user-- which happened due to pushing Git files as the root user.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was the execution order of tasks ran by [Grunt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grunt_(software)).

It was executing the task `connect` that sets up the local server and automatically opens the application in a new tab before executing `less` and `postcss` that [transpile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source-to-source_compiler) styles.

Basically, I changed this:

```javascript
grunt.registerTask('default', 'Start server. Process styles.', ['connect', 'less', 'postcss']);
```

To this:

```javascript
grunt.registerTask('default', 'Process styles. Start server.', ['less', 'postcss', 'connect']);
```

And it worked!

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar error and found that the error was adding '/' at the end of the style.css link href.

Replacing `<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css/">` with `<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

In case you're working with a [Node.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js) application, make sure that the `\public` folder is immediately below the root folder, and not within the views folder.

This can become troublesome. Move the `\public` immediately below the root and then restart the server and witness the changes.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem.

I change my directories' permission to [755](https://chmodcommand.com/chmod-755/) ((U)ser / owner can read, can write and can execute. (G)roup can read, can't write and can execute. (O)thers can read, can't write and can execute.) and now all the files are loading.

You can also try my answer. I hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

I faced this challenge with [Select2](https://select2.org/). It got resolved after I downloaded the latest version of the library and replaced the one (the CSS and JavaScript files) in my project.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the **problem was solved just after changing the random value in the .scss file**. After reloading the problem disappeared and the styles began to load well. Simple, but works :P

Answer (score 1):

I have used a virtual domain in my [XAMPP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XAMPP) installation and got this issue. So in the **httpd-vshosts.conf** file when I checked, I had explicitly pointed to the *index.php* file and this had caused the issue.

So I changed this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/cv/index.php"
    ServerName cv.dv
</VirtualHost>
```

to this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/cv/"
    ServerName cv.dv
</VirtualHost>
```

And then the files were loaded without issues.

Answer (score 1):

In my [Angular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_(web_framework))-[Ionic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ionic_(mobile_app_framework)) project I've a CSS entry like this for a component which would only load when I request.

```
 .searchBar {
    // --placeholder-color: white;
    // --color: white;
    // --icon-color: white;
    // --border-radius: 20px;
    // --background: color:rgba(73,76,67,1.0);
    // --placeholder-opacity: 100%;
    // background-color: red;
  }
```

As soon as I commented out all the values inside the CSS class entry, it started working again.

I think this was happening due to having these properties `background-color` with `--background` together.

Comment: `//` is not a valid comment character sequence in CSS (only the C-style one is, `/*   */`). This is also indicated by the weird syntax highlighting here. It *will* break in some browsers (e.g., it may ignore all or part of the rest of the CSS (terminate parsing)).

Answer (score 1):

I would like this share some thoughts on this topic, when I place

```
app.use(expres.static('../frontEnd/public'))
```

it don't work, but when I use

```
app.use(express.static('/frontEnd/public'))
```

it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Please also check for typos in your filename. This happened to me:

```
style.css.css
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution that worked for me was changing the CSS filename from "style.css" to another name, like "component.css". It worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and after hours of debugging I found out that it is related to temporary files not able to be written.

Go to *Admin* → *Config* → *File system*. Set the correct temporary directory. Make sure your server has permission to write to that directory.

Comment: What application?

Answer (score 0):

**Resaving a .ts file** (forcing [Ionic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ionic_(mobile_app_framework)) to rebuild) solved it for me.

It doesn't really make sense... but as long as it works, who am I to judge?

Here I have seen this workaround:
*[Ionic and Angular 2 - Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:8100/build/main.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48977389/ionic-angular2-refused-to-apply-style-from-http-localhost8100-build-main-c)*

Answer (score 0):

I tried to restart my Windows machine and reinstalled the "npm i".

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Faced the similar issue and solved it using this simple fix. If your project is React based then instead of importing your "styles.css" in "index.html", import it in "index.js" which generally resides inside "src" folder of your project. This will make sure that all your routes inside your React Application has access to the styles file.

Answer (score 0):

Another cause can be the two Apache *.conf* files, where, if your configuration forces HTTPS, then your server will overlook variables set in your *sites-enabled/http-default.conf*.  For example, if you have "/static" defined in *http-default.conf*, but not *https-ssl.conf* then your static files may not get found, i.e., [404](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404).

Answer (score 0):

The path was different for `localhost` and while accessible via `file://` & when deployed...

Answer (score 0):

In my case I host a static website (vuejs 3 with vite 5) that uses tailwindcss on Cloudflare Pages. I solved my 404 issue with two actions:

1. I added in my index.html two references:

   ```html
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="en">
     <head>
       <meta charset="utf-8" />
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
       <link href="output.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
       <link href="dist/output.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
       <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" sizes="32x32">
       <link rel="icon" href="/icon.svg" type="image/svg+xml">
       <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/apple-touch-icon.png"><!-- 180×180 -->
       <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.webmanifest">
       <title>ML on GIS</title>
     </head>
     <body>
       <div id="root"></div>
       <script type="module" src="/src/main.ts"></script>
     </body>
   </html>
   ```
2. The Cloudflare Pages build process instead missed the tailwind css creation step so I defined the build command this way:

   ```bash
   pnpm tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./dist/output.css && pnpm
   build
   ```

That's it in my case.

Answer (score -1):

For Node.js users, use this.
This should solve the problem for Node.js.

`app.use(express.static('static'));`

Answer (score -1):

Adding `<base href="/">` in `public/index.html` in my React application solved the issue for me as well.

[image: solved]

Comment: What is the theory behind it? Why does it work? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74788082/edit), not here in comments (but ***** ***** ***** ***** ***** ***** ***without*** ***** ***** ***** ***** ***** *****  "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score -6):

You must have imported multiple style sheets. Try to remove one and try again.