# Refused to apply style from... because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported style-sheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, mime-types

This error shows only in chrome. I am searching this issue but not yet found any
 satisfactory solution.I attached a screenshot of that error. Please suggest some idea for this. [Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6IAxV.png)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Stylesheets should have a MIME type of `text/css`. Your server is serving up a HTML document (probably a 404 NOT FOUND error page) when it should be serving a CSS document.

Comment: Thanks  can you give some idea how to change MIME type in MVC  .net application.

Comment: Hi, I tried this and found that it didn't have any effect, but changing the src attribute did, as per my answer below. Do you have any thoughts as to why this may be the case? Thanks.

Comment: @Jordan. The two urls clearly resolve to different locations, Regardless of what the current folder is. the relative url has the "css" folder inside the "public" folder, while the absolute url doesn't. If this doesn't satisfy you, you should ask a new question.

Comment: @Alohci yes that was just the way I typed them in - the paths are correct in the actual code.

Comment: You should provide more explanation. The one you gave is not really helpful.

Answer (score 2):

**Solution**:
In my case, the problem was an empty `@GetMapping` in one of my Controllers. I deleted it and the problem was gone.

I think the same answer will help someone who's having this similar problem and context ; e.g. JSP.

**Background**:
I had the same problem using Spring Boot and FreeMaker.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26348955)

Comment: It's really answer, I searched for this answer for 3 days, re-reading a bunch of topics with a similar error and not where this solution was not directly written. Although there were short explanations of why this could happen, it is because, in my case, the empty @GetMapping  overrides servlet by default and the browser receives  in the response not CSS but something else with MIME type text/html, but this is not obvious from the error.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that using a path that includes the domain, rather than just a relative path to the file, fixes the issue.

I.e:

`src="https://<domain>.com/public/css/style.css"`

rather than:

`src="../../public/css/style.css"`

I don't have a reason as to why this is the case. Perhaps something to do with the way static files are being served, or because it needs to be served over `https`. I'm using Firebase to host / serve.

Note that this works for both `css` and `js` files, and explicitly setting the MIME type didn't have an effect for me.

Answer (score 0):

Someone in my team had put the `<link></link>` tags for the css were above and outside the `<head></head>` tags in the `masterPage.html` file.

When this .html file was converted into the `masterPage.master` file, we got these errors. resolution was to place the `<link>` tags inside the `<head>` tags after which the converted `.master` file worked as intended.

Adding this here because this cause was not covered on stackOverflow, including this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48248832) - hope it could help someone in the future

Answer (score 0):

Was having the same problem using firebase hosting, the solution was to move the style sheets to the "public" folder, i am guessing this is because it wasn't being deployed.