# Angular Material - Refused to apply style

Tags: css, angular, angular-material-5

I want to use angular material but facing the problem while importing angular material theme css file -
I imported
`<link href="../node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css" rel="stylesheet">` in the `index.html` but I have this error =>

> Getting the following error -
>    `'http://localhost:8081/node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.`

How do I have to make it work please?
I don't have `angular.json` or `angular-cli.json`

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48248832/stylesheet-not-loaded-because-of-mime-type

Comment: @Olearn I tried but it doesn't work :/

Answer (score -2):

Please Refer [Docs](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started#step-4-include-a-theme) there is specific steps to get started,

**Step 4** from Material Doc,

> Step 4: **Include a theme**

```
Including a theme is required to apply all of the core and theme styles to your application.

To get started with a prebuilt theme, include one of Angular Material's prebuilt themes globally in your application.
```

> If you're using the Angular CLI, you can add this to your **styles.css** or **styles.scss**:

```
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";
```

Comment: I followed the doc of material but precisely it doesn't work :/  I have the error described as above