# Refused to apply style from css because its mime type ('text/html') is not supported

Tags: reactjs

I get the below error for my reactjs project. I have shown my folder structure.

> Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:8093/css/style.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stylesheet not loaded because of MIME-type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48248832/stylesheet-not-loaded-because-of-mime-type)

Comment: agree with the duplicate suggestion.  tldr:  there is probably something other than css code in the css file (comments are the most likely candidate).

Comment: I see that link and that did not fix my issue.

Comment: if the duplicate doesn't apply, please post the contents of your css file for review.

Comment: The css file is currently empty.

Comment: so then what styles were you expecting it to apply??

Comment: I'm trying to add some styles but first the files are not recognized itself. Trying to fix that issue before I can add some styles.

Comment: devServer: {
    contentBase: './dist'
  }..This is my webpack.config file...The devserver contentbase is ./dist..

Comment: If you serve the files from something other than webpack Dev server does the problem persist? Try `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` or `npx serve`

Comment: And if you delete / recreate the file does it persist?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1):

you can import that file in "index.js" instead of directly adding it to "index.html",
it will work for me.[Alternative of this problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mS1Eb.png)