# Can't link CSS / JS files in HTML file

Tags: html, css, express

I'm having problems with linking CSS and JS files in my HTML file's head.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="client.js" type="script"></script>
  </head>
```

File paths look like this:

```
>node modules
-package.json
-package-lock.json
-server.js // Make the express and socket.io stuffs
>main //folder
   -index.html 
   -style.css
   -client.js
```

I've looked at a lot of previous threads about this but nothing fixed my issue.

Both the CSS and JS files are correct, there aren't any errors in them, or at least my editor (VS code) says so.

The console gives me this error:

> Refused to apply a style from 'http://localhost:3000/style.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

Comment: Stylesheet may be detected as html file if starts with comments.

Comment: There are no comments in any of my files

Comment: Also check if `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));` doesn't have forwarding slash at the end, the reference to the files should start with slash like `/style.css`

Comment: nope - `app.use(express.static('public'));`

Answer (score 0):

Please try to remove the comments from the beginning of the  style file
for more info check this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48270432/5092690

Comment: "
There are no comments in any of my files – Mxm 11 mins ago
"

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
```

with

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
```

Comment: I don't think this can be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem while using visual studio code
the css and javascriplt files are not connected to my HTML file although I have checked everything and its all correct
it's solved when I type "link" in the text editor, I choose "link:css" from the dropdown menu of Auto complete
and the same idea with javascript file type "script" and choose "script:src"

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question.