# Sharepoint not a supported stylesheet MIME type

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

I'm getting the below error in share point, when I have done customization in theme.css

Refused to apply style from "//mySite.com/_themes/abc/theme.css" css because its MIME type ('application/octet-stream') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

I know this post is nearly a year old, but the links posted by Purushottam actually have tons of different solutions, most of which did not seem to pertain to SharePoint.  Additionally, links are prone to disappearance.  The solution that worked for me in SharePoint 2013 was adding `<base href="/">` before my CSS links.  I was using JSLink and some jQuery to modify a list's display and apply custom css.  Here is my jQuery code that I used.  Hope it helps to anyone else finding this issue in SharePoint.

```
    '<base href="/">',
    '<link rel="stylesheet" href="../_catalogs/masterpage/Display Templates/listAccordion.css" type="text/css">',
  );
```

Answer (score -1):

Please check these links:
[Stylesheet not loaded because of MIME-type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48248832/stylesheet-not-loaded-because-of-mime-type)

https://github.com/froala/angular-froala/issues/170

https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Technical-Issues/Refused-to-apply-style-quot-because-its-MIME-type-text-html-is/td-p/86721

Thanks and regards,
Purushottam