# How to change MIME type for browser to render css file?

Tags: css, node.js, ejs, mime

My css code is not rendering in the browser and it has something to do with mime types(which i know nothing about). I am using ejs as a template engine.Here's the error i get in console....

> Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:3000/assets/styles.css'
>   because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME
>   type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

I'm a NodeJs beginner so maybe thats the problem? Is there a package or any other way to fix this problem? It's not a directory problem because I have followed multiple tutorials and still the same problem.

Comment: How are you serving the files?  Post your code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stylesheet not loaded because of MIME-type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48248832/stylesheet-not-loaded-because-of-mime-type)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a CSS preprocessor(SCSS, Sass, LESS or POST-CSS) just try recompiling the preprocessor code in the right directory(whichever directory you want to keep the CSS code in)

For me, it just worked after I recompiled it in the right destination.