# Angular Print window for added css part does not work

Tags: css, angular

I added **Angular 6 QR code print window** for following  `printqrcode.component.ts` scripts but that style part not working in print view
Any one know how to add `printqrcode.component.css` correctly  for the scripts

I got a google console error

> VM53323 locations:1 Refused to apply style from
>   'http://localhost:4200/printqrcode.component.css' because its MIME
>   type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict
>   MIME checking is enabled.

**printqrcode.component.ts**

```
printSelectedArea(){
    console.log('Print selected Area!');
    let innerContents = document.getElementById('printToPDF').innerHTML;
    console.log('innerContents : ',innerContents);

    let popupWinindow = window.open('', '_blank', 'width=600,height=700,scrollbars=no,menubar=no,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,titlebar=no');

    popupWinindow.document.open();
    popupWinindow.document.write('<html><head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="printqrcode.component.css" /> QR Code </head><body  onload="window.print()">' + innerContents + '</html>');
    popupWinindow.document.close();

  }
```

**printqrcode.component.css**

```
.custom-control {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  min-height: 1.5rem;
  padding-left: 0rem;
}

/*QR CODE*/
.img-responsive {

  display: inline-block;
}
/*QR CODE*/

.qr-cde .card {background:#f4f6f9;}
.rounds {
  position: relative;
}

.rounds label {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 28px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 28px;
}

.rounds label:after {
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-top: none;
  border-right: none;
  content: "";
  height: 6px;
  left: 7px;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  width: 12px;
}

.rounds input[type="checkbox"] {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.rounds input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label {
  background-color: #06d79c;
  border-color: #06d79c;
}

.rounds input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
.qr-grt {padding: 60px;}
@media (min-width: 768px)
{
          .col-md-3 {
            flex: 0 0 25%;
            max-width: 40%;
          }}



.print-new-section .col-3 {
  flex: 0 0 25%;
  max-width: 25%;
  margin: 5px 5px; border: 1px solid lightgrey;
}
span qrcode.center {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto; width: 200px;
  margin-right: auto;border: 1px solid #e8e8e8;

  margin-right: auto;
}

.qr-spantext {color: black;
  font-weight: bold;}

.rm-nme {font-size: 12px; color: #1c2128; text-align: center; }
.lc-name {font-size: 12px; color: #1c2128; text-align: center; }
```

Comment: This thread might help you with this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48248832/8365253

Comment: @HariniP Thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the some solutions, i removed

external .css file and `popupWinindow.document.write('<html><head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="printqrcode.component.css" /> QR Code </head><body  onload="window.print()">' + innerContents + '</html>');`

I added my css part using **inline**

```
popupWinindow.document.write('<html><head><style>css here...</style> QR Code </head><body  onload="window.print()">' + innerContents + '</html>');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a `CSS` file (eg. `styles.css`), it should be placed into `assets` folder. Than, add a `link` into printing page:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/styles.css" />
```

This works to me.