# Angular 7 "Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:4200/css/main.css'

Tags: angular

I am trying to access an external URL, I am getting this error on my Console.
Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:4200/css/main.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
css/main.css is getting rendered from external URL
Please help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stylesheet not loaded because of MIME-type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48248832/stylesheet-not-loaded-because-of-mime-type)

Comment: How are the css files refereed to from the html?