# Facing problem regarding live-server in Atom and NodeJS

Tags: node.js, npm-live-server

I want to set a live environment for my web application. I'm using AngularJS and NodeJS (MEAN) and I want both to run live simultaneously. What I did is, I installed live-server through npm and started server by

```
live-server --`host=192.168.XX.XX --port=9999`
```

It is showing the following error:

> Refused to apply style from 'http://192.168.XX.XX:9999/main.css'
>   because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME
>   type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

Also tried giving the path to my project folder in public by

```
live-server --`host=192.168.XX.XX --port=9999` --open=public
```

but facing same error. Please help! Thankyou

Comment: Please check your css files for unnecessary texts and comments .Can you post a snippetof how you are including your css files

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stylesheet not loaded because of MIME-type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48248832/stylesheet-not-loaded-because-of-mime-type)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was just the other index.html file i placed outside the public folder.
By the way, one solution worked for me.

Place this link in the head of your HTML.

```
<base href="/" target="_blank">
```

Answer (score 0):

First I would check to see if you have a typo in the path name in the script tag.  If you have an extra `/` in the name then you will get this error.

Second, try minifying the css file.