# Css Not applied in angular 6

Tags: angular

Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:4200/bower_components/uikit/css/uikit.almost-flat.min.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

Comment: Hello and welcome! Is this an angular error..?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stylesheet not loaded because of MIME-type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48248832/stylesheet-not-loaded-because-of-mime-type)