# Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:1234/node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css' because its MIME type ('text/html')

Tags: angular, primeng

I am getting below error while adding below styles in `index.html` in Angular 6 application.

> Refused to apply the style from
>   'http://localhost:1234/node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css' because
>   its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type,
>   and strict MIME checking is enabled.

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/nova-light/theme.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css" />
```

How should I fix this error?

Comment: Possible duplicate to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48248832/stylesheet-not-loaded-because-of-mime-type

Comment: remove them from *index.html* & declare in *angular.json*

Comment: best approach is to add styles in your style.css/scss file

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of adding style in your `index.html` add it in your `style.css` file like below

**Style.css**

```
  @import '~primeicons/primeicons.css';
  @import '~primeng/resources/themes/nova-light/theme.css';
  @import '~primeng/resources/primeng.min.css';
```

Hop this will help!

Answer (score 2):

You have several options, how to import styles.

**Import to CSS**

*styles.css*

```
@import '~primeicons/primeicons.css';
@import '~primeng/resources/themes/nova-light/theme.css';
@import '~primeng/resources/primeng.min.css';
```

**Or add them to angular.json**

You can also add them to the `angular.json` file.

```
{
 ...
   "projects": {
    "yourProjectName": {
      ...
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/SkolniPanely",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.png",
              "src/assets",
              "src/manifest.json"
            ],
            "styles": [
              //Here you can add *.css files
            ],
            "scripts": [
              //Here you can add *.js files
            ]
          },
          ...
```