# How to add CSS on the print page?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular7, angular8

I want to add the style for the section which I am going to print.

```
 let popupWinindow
 let innerContents = this.printDiv.nativeElement.innerHTML;
 popupWinindow = window.open('', '_blank', 'top=0,left=0,height=100%,width=auto');
 popupWinindow.document.open();
 popupWinindow.document.write('<html><head><link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></head><body onload="window.print();">' + innerContents + '</html>');
 popupWinindow.document.close();
```

When I am adding styles internally in the style tag then everything works fine.
But when I tried to add it in external way it does not apply to the printDiv.

This is the error I have in console.

```
Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:4200/styles.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

Comment: Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48248832/stylesheet-not-loaded-because-of-mime-type)

Comment: Try downloading http://localhost:4200/styles.css, enter it in the address bar in your browser and verify that you get a css document and not a 404 html error page

Comment: i am getting an error page so what should i do for it ?So, that it will automatically get access

Comment: You should use the full absolute path to your style sheet (including protocol and domain)

Answer (score 1):

The opened window is somewhat unrelated to to opening window. It doesn't know of the path to your file and the domain and the protocol. You should insert the complete absolute URL to your style sheet in your code.

So if your style sheet file resides on `https://example.com/path/to/file/style.css`, you should use

```
 popupWinindow.document.write('<html><head><link href="https://example.com/path/to/file/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></head><body onload="window.print();">' + innerContents + '</html>');
```

See https://codepen.io/HerrSerker/pen/70cdc072c09f04b850b67febe7ef0f34 for a working demonstration

You can get the path information to your html file dynamically in JS with

```
location.protocol + "//" + location.host + location.pathname.replace(/\/(?!.*\/).*$/, '/')
```

Answer (score 0):

For printing you should add a mediaquery `print`

```
@media print {
   // Your styles
}
```

Also check the path to the `styles.css` file. For example here you can find more info [Stylesheet not loaded because of MIME-type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48248832/stylesheet-not-loaded-because-of-mime-type)

Comment: my question is, its not taking the styles.css directly.

Comment: I have already refer this link  and my css file name is "styles.css" and its under the folder src/styles.css

Comment: Hm, can you reproduce the problem on stackblitz?