# I want to link to my external CSS file in my HTML file

Tags: html, css, linker

This is my path for my HTML file:
C:\Users\Lorenzo\Desktop\Capstone Project\HTML\index.html

and this is my path for my CSS file:
C:\Users\Lorenzo\Desktop\Capstone Project\CSS\style.css

Comment: Are you running this HTML in a web server, or have you loaded it in your browser directly from your file system?

Comment: l loaded it directly from my file system. (I am using Visual Studio Code)

Comment: In the short term, hardwire the full path, so `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:\Users\Lorenzo\Desktop\Capstone Project\CSS\style.css">`, and then set up a web server when you can. This will help you make it clear that `C:\Users\Lorenzo\Desktop\Capstone Project` is your project root and not `C:\Users\Lorenzo\Desktop\Capstone Project\HTML`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../CSS/style.css">
// or 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="..\\CSS\\style.css">
```

to your `index.html` file

---

**Notice:** If you're using `Live Server` on VSCode *(like me)*. You have to open VSCode with the folder `Capstone Project\`, **not `HTML\`**, or you'll run into an error

> Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:3000/CSS/style.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

That error has been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48248832/stylesheet-not-loaded-because-of-mime-type)

Answer (score 0):

link your CSS on head part of HTML file

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
   <!-- link your style.css file -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

<!-- your HTML page body -->

</body>
</html>
```