# Refused to apply style from 'URL' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled

Tags: html, css, express, sass, ejs

**Here's my stack**

- Express
- Ejs
- Sass (installed by 'npm install --save-dev sass' - a dev dependency)

---

I'm getting an error of

> Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:3000/css/style.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

---

my head tag is on a separate partials folder:
- views 
- - partials
- - - header.ejs
- - index.ejs

my CSS is also on another folder
- public
- - css
- - - style.css
- - - style.css.map
- - - style.scss

---

my head tag looks like this:

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Learn Web</title>
<base href="/">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
</head>
```

---

I render my index like this:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index');
})
```

---

I tried adding `<base href="/">`
I tried to omit `rel="stylesheet"`
I tried to change the `type="text/css"` to `type="text/html"` - It got rid of the error but the styles do not apply.

---

> Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stylesheet not loaded because of MIME-type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48248832/stylesheet-not-loaded-because-of-mime-type)

Comment: Is `http://localhost:3000/css/style.css` actually serving the CSS document as opposed to e.g. an HTML error message?

Comment: "I render my index like this:" — How do you render the CSS?

Comment: ("I render my index like this:" — How do you render the CSS?) - with a <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So i solved the issue. But it's somehow a half fix. Because I'm just starting my project when I encountered this issue. I restart my project but by using the express-generator where it automatically create an application skeleton. Then after that, I installed Sass using npm and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this line to your js file will allow the local css to link:
app.use(express.static(__dirname));

You can read about serving static files in Express here:
http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html