# Cannot Import Google Fonts in Gatsby SCSS

Tags: sass, gatsby, netlify, google-fonts

** EDIT **
Nah, the problem is the css2 api who use wght@500:
so i must escape the @ and : with %40 and %3B and now its fixed.
but someone told me its better to use gatsby plugin typeface, and it slightly improved my site performance. Thanks all
**

I'm new to GatsbyJS and I'm trying to modify TaniaRascia's static blog template, the system works fine. But I cannot import google fonts in my SCSS file. I see this error on her site too. Any solutions?

The Code :

```
/*! Primitive

by Tania Rascia */

@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@500;600;700&display=swap);

@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Mono);

// Configuration

@import 'base/variables';

@import 'base/mixins';
```

The Error in Console :

```
Refused to apply style from '``<SITE_URL>/url``(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@500' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

Instead of importing the css from url, it seems the browser read it as a link from my local directory.

I've tried solutions from the Internet such as :

```
 - #import 'https://....' < this one produces error when i ran gatsby build
 - @import url("https://...'
 - @import url('https://...'
```

And 2 of them produces same error "Refused to apply style from...."

Any solutions? Thanks

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48248832/stylesheet-not-loaded-because-of-mime-type

Comment: @RobinMétral nope, i have tried that. But i got mine fixed

Answer (score 1):

Can you try using this meta:

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="style-src 'self' https://fonts.googleapis.com; font-src 'self' https://fonts.gstatic.com;">
```

Either using `react-helmet` or via the `html.js` Gatsby template. [Instructions on how to customize html.js here](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/custom-html/)

Comment: thanks Cole. Someone recommends me to use typeface, so its fixed now. I'll try yours too and compare the performance, thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

What about the [gatsby-plugin-prefetch-google-fonts plugin](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-prefetch-google-fonts/)? I use that within my scss files.

```
body {
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
}
```

inside gatsby-config:

```
{
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-prefetch-google-fonts`,
      options: {
        fonts: [
          {
            family: `Raleway`,
          },
        ],
      },
    },
```