# NodeJS express add style.css static

Tags: node.js, express, static

I add static CSS,

and this file exists in source code of the page,

but CSS not applied...

In console wrote "blocking CSS because MIMO type does not define correctly"

In link tag type='text/css' exist.

Ask is how I can define 'Content-type' in express automatically?

Comment: Check if this posts answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48248832/stylesheet-not-loaded-because-of-mime-type

Comment: Your right, after 3 hours I finally find incorrect in path

Answer (score 1):

You can create public folder and add all the client side files.

In your server side you must use it :

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

with path module :

```
npm install path
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue yesterday and solved it.
So first node uses folder path to get files.
That means that if you're at `http://localhost:3000/` you are at the root of your directory. also you can access your stylesheet via `http://localhost:3000/public/css/style.css`.

But, you can modify the path using routes and `express.static()`.

You may have an url which is `http://localhost:3000/user/index`. So he is seeking for the css file such as `http://localhost:3000/user/public/css/style.css` which does not exist.

the solution might be to use different route files like this :

```
app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);
```

Comment: Thanks, but in my case was just broken path