# Docker shows blank local container, console shows “Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404”

Tags: python, django, docker, dockerfile, gunicorn

I am trying to run a Docker container locally, via the command:

`docker run --rm -d  mellon:latest`

The gunicorn command which is executing is:

`gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:8000 mellon.wsgi`

(more specifically in the Dockerfile):

```
...

EXPOSE 8000

CMD python3 manage.py makemigrations && \
    python3 manage.py migrate && \
    gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:8000 mellon.wsgi
```

Everything in the terminal seems fine, this is the end of what I see:

```
...
[2020-07-28 14:52:33 +0000] [10] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
[2020-07-28 14:52:33 +0000] [10] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (10)
[2020-07-28 14:52:33 +0000] [10] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2020-07-28 14:52:33 +0000] [12] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 12
```

So I then go to http://localhost:8000/ yet I just see a completely blank screen with the title and favicon of the project in the tab (see below).
[image]

This isn't an issue with caching, as I have tried it in a few browsers and the favicon and title appear there too. And upon using 'inspect element' on the page, it shows the contents of the `index.html` file of my Vue.js project there (located in `mellon/frontend/dist`). It isn't a problem with my project as running the front-end server (`npm run serve`) and the back-end server (`python3 manage.py runserver`) as I usually do shows everything to be fine on `localhost:8080`.

What could possibly be causing this issue?

Edit: After checking the console in Google Chrome, I see these errors:

[image]

I am unsure of how to solve these issues.

Comment: Did you try to inspect page in chrome? Is there is any errors in console?

Comment: @Adiii yes, please see the edit

Comment: This is related to the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48248832/stylesheet-not-loaded-because-of-mime-type

Comment: @olahsymbo how so? I am struggling to find what to actually fix

Comment: Gunicorn is running fine. However, the browser is not getting your stylesheet. You probably aren't referencing it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a weird way of solving this. If you look at my screenshot of the console in Google Chrome, there is just a bunch of 'chunk' files. I did a fresh pull from my Git repository (where the .gitignore ignored all of these kind of files) and everything worked perfectly fine.