# MIME type Error Django/React project on PythonAnywhere

Tags: css, reactjs, django, pythonanywhere

I've used PythonAnywhere before, but this is the first project that utilizes a Django back end and React front end.  What is strange is that if I run this exact project on localhost, there are no troubles at all.  It is only when I host this website on PythonAnywhere do I get this error.

[image: Error messages on the right.]

They're probably hard to see...

> Refused to apply style from 'http://bluebirdteaching.pythonanywhere.com/static/css/2.8aa5a7f8.chunk.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

Looking this up, I've come across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48248832/stylesheet-not-loaded-because-of-mime-type) page a lot, but I just can't seem to make sense of the answers provided there.  I just don't understand why this works on localhost, but not on PythonAnywhere.

[image]

I included the above image not just to show my index.html, but also to show the project directory as that seems to be necessary as the other post linked explains.  If the answer I'm looking for is in that other post, I just can't make sense of it.

Again, everything works as expected when I run the project locally.  Of course, thanks guys for any help.  I've been going at this problem for a while now; any help/explanations would be a huge relief.

Here is the index.html file generated when I do `npm run build`.  This is where all those chunk.css and chunk.js are referenced.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"/>
        <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000"/>
        <meta name="description" content="Web site created using create-react-app"/>
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/logo192.png"/>
        <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json"/>
        <title>BlueBird Teaching</title>
        <link href="/static/css/2.f3cffc9e.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="/static/css/main.aa904fbe.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
        <div id="root"></div>
        <script>!function(e){function r(r){for(var n,a,p=r[0],l=r[1],f=r[2],c=0,s=[];c<p.length;c++)a=p[c],Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(o,a)&&o[a]&&s.push(o[a][0]),o[a]=0;for(n in l)Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(l,n)&&(e[n]=l[n]);for(i&&i(r);s.length;)s.shift()();return u.push.apply(u,f||[]),t()}function t(){for(var e,r=0;r<u.length;r++){for(var t=u[r],n=!0,p=1;p<t.length;p++){var l=t[p];0!==o[l]&&(n=!1)}n&&(u.splice(r--,1),e=a(a.s=t[0]))}return e}var n={},o={1:0},u=[];function a(r){if(n[r])return n[r].exports;var t=n[r]={i:r,l:!1,exports:{}};return e[r].call(t.exports,t,t.exports,a),t.l=!0,t.exports}a.m=e,a.c=n,a.d=function(e,r,t){a.o(e,r)||Object.defineProperty(e,r,{enumerable:!0,get:t})},a.r=function(e){"undefined"!=typeof Symbol&&Symbol.toStringTag&&Object.defineProperty(e,Symbol.toStringTag,{value:"Module"}),Object.defineProperty(e,"__esModule",{value:!0})},a.t=function(e,r){if(1&r&&(e=a(e)),8&r)return e;if(4&r&&"object"==typeof e&&e&&e.__esModule)return e;var t=Object.create(null);if(a.r(t),Object.defineProperty(t,"default",{enumerable:!0,value:e}),2&r&&"string"!=typeof e)for(var n in e)a.d(t,n,function(r){return e[r]}.bind(null,n));return t},a.n=function(e){var r=e&&e.__esModule?function(){return e.default}:function(){return e};return a.d(r,"a",r),r},a.o=function(e,r){return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e,r)},a.p="/";var p=this.webpackJsonpreactapp=this.webpackJsonpreactapp||[],l=p.push.bind(p);p.push=r,p=p.slice();for(var f=0;f<p.length;f++)r(p[f]);var i=l;t()}([])</script>
        <script src="/static/js/2.f7026f3a.chunk.js"></script>
        <script src="/static/js/main.f2b0e582.chunk.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you set up a [static file mapping](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/StaticFiles/) to serve up your JS and CSS files?

Answer (score 0):

One of the suggestions in the SO post you linked to is that you're may not actually be serving CSS, but may be serving HTML instead. Have you loaded the css page in a browser to see what you're returning from that URL?

Comment: Do you mean typing the path to the CSS file into the browser?  The path to the CSS file is /home/yomen/sample/bluebird/reactapp/src/index.css, and when I typed that into the browser, I got the CSS I expected.  Sorry if that is not what you mean.

Comment: I also did some digging through to see what this chunck.css stuff is.  It seems to be a weirder, one line version of my index.css file.  The index.css is the actual CSS that I wrote.  Chunk.css seems to the generated when I did npm run build.

Comment: Also, when I do npm run build, it builds an HTML file that references that CSS file, and doesn't seem to actually use index.css.

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind why it shows mime type error is that, staticfiles_dirs doesn't include src folder, and if there is images inside src, it doesn't get include in staticfiles folder while collectstatic process, hence throws error.

so make sure to not use import images inside src or public, instead host them.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Migrating solution from the question to an answer:</sub>

> The reason why it was working locally but not on Heroku or PythonAnywhere was because I needed to set out mapping for static files. All I needed to do was run `python3 manage.py collectstatic`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me,

1. Add these in settings.py

   ```
   # URL path where static files will be served from.
   STATIC_URL = '/static/'

   # Define the directory where Django will collect static files during production.
   STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

   # Additional directories where Django will look for static files.
   STATICFILES_DIRS = [
       os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'frontend', 'build', 'static'),
   ]

   WHITENOISE_MIMETYPES = {
       '.css': 'text/css',
       '.js': 'text/javascript'
   }
   ```
2. Considering you have your react app build in frontend/build/.
   Inside this folder, there will be a static/ folder and some files. These files should be present in frontend/public/ folder as well
3. Then you should run collect static command in your virtual environment

   ```
   python manage.py collectstatic
   ```
4. Copy the content of staticfiles/ folder to frontend/build/static/

So your frontend/build/static/ folder should have the folders created by,

```
npm run build
```

and contents of staticfiles/ folder