# Browser refused to apply my external CSS styles

Tags: javascript, html, css, localhost, mime

I've created a website which is running on a local server.

The local host server is up and running, the HTML code is displayed as desired but the browser refused to apply my external CSS styles which I linked to my HTML and the browser keeps telling me in the console:

> "refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:3000/styles.css'
> because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME
> type, and strict MIME checking is enabled."

my css,Htmland javascript files are at the same level in the same directory:

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express()
const request = require("request")
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname+"/signup.html")
})

app.listen("3000", function(){
    console.log("server is up and running on port 3000")
})
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.form-signin {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 330px;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.form-signin .checkbox {
  font-weight: 400;
}
.form-signin .form-control {
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.form-signin .form-control:focus {
  z-index: 2;
}
.form-signin input[type="email"] {
  margin-bottom: -1px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}
.form-signin input[type="password"] {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../../../favicon.ico">

    <title>Newsletter Sign up</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

  </head>

  <body class="text-center">
    <form class="form-signin">
        <img class="mb-4" src="images/recycling-symbol-waste-recycle-bin.jpg" alt="" width="72" height="72">
      <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Please sign in</h1>
      <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
      <input type="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>
      <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
      <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
      <div class="checkbox mb-3">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
        </label>
      </div>
      <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
      <p class="mt-5 mb-3 text-muted">&copy; 2017-2018</p>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.form-signin {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 330px;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.form-signin .checkbox {
  font-weight: 400;
}
.form-signin .form-control {
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.form-signin .form-control:focus {
  z-index: 2;
}
.form-signin input[type="email"] {
  margin-bottom: -1px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}
.form-signin input[type="password"] {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../../../favicon.ico">

    <title>Newsletter Sign up</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

  </head>

  <body class="text-center">
    <form class="form-signin">
        <img class="mb-4" src="images/recycling-symbol-waste-recycle-bin.jpg" alt="" width="72" height="72">
      <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Please sign in</h1>
      <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
      <input type="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>
      <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
      <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
      <div class="checkbox mb-3">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
        </label>
      </div>
      <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
      <p class="mt-5 mb-3 text-muted">&copy; 2017-2018</p>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you show the file structure?

Comment: How did you try to apply the stylesheet? It sounds like you defined it incorrectly, but without any sort of code example it's hard to tell. Please provide all relevant code samples.

Comment: ive updated the question with the codes

Comment: @Damiz  This would probably help you:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48248832/stylesheet-not-loaded-because-of-mime-type