# CSS is working on local server but not on Heroku server

Tags: heroku

I made a simple newsletter sign up page, and it was working fine with the local server, but when I added it to Heroku, for some reason the CSS doesn't work. It shows an error saying "Refused to apply style from '...' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported style sheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.". My CSS seems to be linked correctly, because it works on the local server. If anyone could help me solve this i'd appreciate it, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First answer here should be alright [Stylesheet not loaded because of MIME-type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48248832/stylesheet-not-loaded-because-of-mime-type)
If you are using a Express Server(node js) add your folder on server like this

```
app.use("/public", express.static("public"));
```

Public being the folder where u store your css.

Comment: thank you so much! I added that to my app.js and it fixed it!