# stylesheet not being pulled in correctly

Tags: html, css

Super simple question, but this is not working for me. I have googled it, but for some reason, I am not sure.
I am trying to render my CSS styling in my index.ejs file (essentially my index.html)

My stylesheet is located in `Base Directory > public > css > stylesheet.css`
and my index.ejs file is located in `Base Directory > views > index.ejs`

This is currently how I am trying to pull in my stylesheet in my index.ejs:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href= "/public/css/stylesheet.css" />
```

Is there anything wrong with this approach?

Edit:
Using `href= "../public/css/stylesheet.css"`  and CMD+click I am able to go to the stylesheet, so the syntax above must be correct... but it is not rendering

Note: I am also using express

Answer (score 0):

It should not be with respect to the `HTML` file and not the `base directory`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href= "../public/css/stylesheet.css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

`href="../public/css/stylesheet.css"`

. Most probably your `href` is searching for the `stylesheet.css` in the `public/css/stylesheet` of the current directory (which doesn't exist) instead of  `Base Directory`

Comment: Nope, that doesn't work either. Using `href= "../public/css/stylesheet.css" ` and CMD+click I am able to go to the stylesheet, so the syntax above must be correct... but it is not rendering...

Comment: can you make sure that the css file is being loaded in the browser? check the `Resources` and `Network` tabs under the dev tools of your browser and see if you can locate the css file.

Comment: Ah... I assume this is the issue
`Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:3000/public/css/stylesheet.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.`

Comment: Checkout [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48248832/stylesheet-not-loaded-because-of-mime-type]

Answer (score 0):

Using `/css/stylesheet.css` worked.

Becuase I am using

```
app.use(express.static(join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

In my express file, the href already includes /public