# Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:3000/assets/styles/signup.css' because its MIME type('text/html')is not a supported stylesheet MIME type

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, express

Similar questions have been asked and I'm asking again **after reading many of them([including this most upvoted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48248832/stylesheet-not-loaded-because-of-mime-type)), trying and getting no positive results and banging my head for around two hours**. Please look into this. I'm learning some web dev. and am trying to build this [bootstrap signup page](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/sign-in/). However I'm stuck on the very  early stage. Attaching the code files:(zip file uploaded at Gofile.io, link at the end)

Error I'm getting on chrome console:

```
Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:3000/assets/styles/bootstrap.min.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
localhost/:1 Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:3000/assets/styles/signup.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
localhost/:39 GET http://localhost:3000/assets/images/bootstrap-solid.svg 404 (Not Found)
```

On opening any link to new tab, I'm getting(example for bootsrap-image):

`Cannot GET /assets/images/bootstrap-solid.svg`

I'm using Google Chrome latest version on Windows 10 OS.

Apart from `package.json` and `app.js` , I've copied all html and css bootstrap example source code.

```
directory structure--

Newsletter-signup
|_assets
|      |_images
|      |    |_bootstrap-solid.svg
|      |    |_favicon.ico
|      |
|      |_styles
|            |_bootstrap.min.css
|            |_signup.css
|
|_app.js
|_package.json
|_signup.html
```

package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "Newsletter-Signup",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon app.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7"
  }
}
```

app.js:

```js
import express from "express";
import https from "https";
import path from "path";

const app = express();
const __dirname = path.resolve();
const portNumber = 3000;
// console.log(__dirname);

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "assets")));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "signup.html"));
});

app.post("/", () => {
  console.log("called app.post method");
});

app.listen(portNumber, () => {
  console.log("server listening at portNumber: " + portNumber);
});
```

signup.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
    />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="author" content="" />
    <link rel="icon" href="assets/images/favicon.ico" />

    <title>Signup Form</title>

    <!-- <link
      rel="canonical"
      href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/sign-in/"
    /> -->

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link
      type="text/css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="assets/styles/bootstrap.min.css"
    />

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="assets/styles/signup.css" />
  </head>

  <body class="text-center">
    <form class="form-signin">
      <img
        class="mb-4"
        src="assets/images/bootstrap-solid.svg"
        alt=""
        width="72"
        height="72"
      />
      <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Please sign in</h1>
      <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
      <input
        type="email"
        id="inputEmail"
        class="form-control"
        placeholder="Email address"
        required
        autofocus
      />
      <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
      <input
        type="password"
        id="inputPassword"
        class="form-control"
        placeholder="Password"
        required
      />
      <div class="checkbox mb-3">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me" /> Remember me
        </label>
      </div>
      <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">
        Sign in
      </button>
      <p class="mt-5 mb-3 text-muted">&copy; 2017-2018</p>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

signup.css

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.form-signin {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 330px;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.form-signin .checkbox {
  font-weight: 400;
}
.form-signin .form-control {
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.form-signin .form-control:focus {
  z-index: 2;
}
.form-signin input[type="email"] {
  margin-bottom: -1px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}
.form-signin input[type="password"] {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
}
```

If I use CDN for bootstrap then bootstrap part works. *Also, without node, if I simply paste path of `signup.html` in browser, it is working fine.*

**You can download and check the complete source file from [here](https://gofile.io/d/lmIqlK)**

Comment: What do you see in the Network tab of your browser devtools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, browser request to `http://localhost:3000/assets/styles/signup.css` returns a 404 page with "text/html" content (you can check this in Developer Tools of your browser).
That's wht you receive error `MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.`

Remove the "assets" word from your assets URLs:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/signup.css" />
```

Also, you can check if it works by pasting full CSS link in your browser tab input.

Comment: Oooh man This worked immediately :D !!! Thanks a ton! By the way, I'm just curious how did you think of that? Why It's working while not even writing the complete path of static files?

Comment: Take a look at the [doc for express.static()](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html).

Comment: @T.M15 you configured `express.static` with `"assets"` static directory and "Express looks up the files relative to the static directory, so the name of the static directory is not part of the URL. " from [official docs](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the urls in your html code from stuff like

```
 assets/styles/bootstrap.min.css
```

to

```
 /assets/styles/bootstrap.min.css
```

And look at your Network tab to see what's going on. Often these "refused to apply style" error messages crop up because the browser responded with a 404 page rather than the style sheet you wanted.

Comment: Ya! tried that also earlier but the result was negative. Btw, the issue is solved now, though I'll remember the advice of checking network tab for future debuggings. Thanks for taking time :)