# Refused to apply style from styles.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet when reloading specific route

Tags: angular

I get the errors [enter image description [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJnJR.png) when I try to reload specific components.

monitordaten is my component name.

I did some changes in webmanifest before but nothing that could be really related to that.
Thats how my manifest looks like now.

```
  "scope": "./",
  "start_url": "./",
```

How can I fix those errors?

Comment: Make sure that the server's MIME type for .css files is set correctly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stylesheet not loaded because of MIME-type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48248832/stylesheet-not-loaded-because-of-mime-type), in particular [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51078841/1115360).

Comment: Oh, hang on, if it's replying with text/html then that could well be a 404 File not found error page.

Answer (score 0):

Looking into the CSS file path, I guess it points to a nonexisting file.

I suppose placing this style file into the assets folder and reference that folder would solve the issue.

Comment: indeed, I just got scss files, no css. So that could not be the error. But where could this file be set?