# Im getting a strange error ive never seen before with bootstrap and javascript. Does anyone know what it means?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome, mime

Hello I'm getting the following error in the console. I'm using bootstrap or at least trying to...

Refused to apply style from 'http://127.0.0.1:5500/node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

Can anyone tell me wth is going on and how to fix it??

Comment: Please check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48248832/stylesheet-not-loaded-because-of-mime-type

Comment: You should add more information in question that helps others to understand the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stylesheet not loaded because of MIME-type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48248832/stylesheet-not-loaded-because-of-mime-type)

Answer (score 0):

cap, go to network => headers in console. Look to see if there is a 404 associated with your .ccs file.
It is possible that the path to the file is incorrect. My advice would be to route the style sheet (font-awesome) in via the cdn address from the website. This may take away the guess work. Let me know what you find out.

-Kristopher