# Refused to apply style' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, django-templates

here is my code
i am trying to run it on a django server and it is giving me that error
would appreciate and help

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32" />
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16" />
  <title>Travel</title>
  <!--stylesheet-->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="styles/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="styles/custom-responsive-styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <!--scripts-->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/all-plugins.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/plugins-activate.js"></script>
```

Comment: Check this answer, it might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50173968/15867270