# react - Refused to apply style because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

After I run `npm run build`,

package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "build": "react-scripts build"
  },
```

When I go to `index.html`, nothing inside the `<div id="root"></div>`.

When I open `index.html`

When I inspect the `index.html`, the console show errors
[image]

How can I solve it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stylesheet not loaded because of MIME-type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48248832/stylesheet-not-loaded-because-of-mime-type)