# Why I am getting Refused to apply style from css because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported

Tags: php, laravel, heroku

I have a laravel app

I am externally adding css files to my project

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4//owl.carousel.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4//owl.theme.default.min.css">
```

I deployed the laravel app to heroku

I get the following error

Refused to apply style from 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4//owl.carousel.min.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

Any reason

Thanks

Comment: Did you open the URL ? It has nothing, it is a `404`, that is why.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48248832/stylesheet-not-loaded-because-of-mime-type 
Check This. It Should Help Full To You.

Answer (score 1):

URL is wrong
try

```php
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css">
```

Comment: I have custum css and js files  want to include them in heroku. How can I do that ? I tried    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" > it is not working @tipu

Comment: maybe because of storage symlink