# Drupal Refused to apply style from

Tags: drupal, mysql-workbench

[image]

I  Install Drupal in local and when i run It the website runs without css and This error appears :
Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost/drupal_test/' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled

Comment: Did you check the 62 answers from this post ? [Stylesheet not loaded because of MIME-type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48248832/2529954). There are at least 3 duplicates for this question already.

Comment: This one is Drupal sepcific, I'd like to see an answer as to why Drupal would have this issue and how to fix it in the context of Drupal.

Comment: the other answers are not related to drupal ... i want a specific answer concern drupal plateform