# I'm working on website and styles is not displaying

Tags: html, css

index.html:1 Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:8080/style.min.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

Comment: share your folder structure

Comment: Could [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48248832/stylesheet-not-loaded-because-of-mime-type) help?

Comment: possible duplicate of
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48248832/stylesheet-not-loaded-because-of-mime-type

Answer (score 0):

You're saying that it says that the MIME type is text/html, if its a CSS file the MIME type should be text/css.