# Refused to apply style because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported and to load bundle.js file

Tags: html, css, webpack, electron, electron-forge

These are the error messages I'm getting:

```
    Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:3000/search_window/min/dist/bundle.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
    localhost/:1 Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:3000/search_window/min/ext/icons/iconfont.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
    bundle.js:1 
     Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) localhost/:1 Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:3000/search_window/min/dist/bundle.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
    localhost/:1 Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:3000/search_window/min/ext/icons/iconfont.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled."
```

[image]
[image]

In `package.json` :

```
         "mainConfig": "./webpack.main.config.js",
        "devContentSecurityPolicy": "default-src 'unsafe-eval' 'self'; script-src-elem 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; img-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; font-src 'self' https://static2.sharepointonline.com; connect-src 'self' https: http:",
        "renderer": {
          "config": "./webpack.renderer.config.js",
          "entryPoints": [
            {
              "html": "./src/app_S/index_S.html",
              "js": "./src/app_S/renderer_S.ts",
              "css": ["./src/app_S/min/dist/bundle.css", "./src/app_S/min/ext/iconfont.css"],
              "preload": {
                "js": "./src/main/preload/preload.ts"
              },
              "name": "search_window"
```

In `/src/app_S/index_S.html` :

And in `app_S/min/dist` :

```
-rw-rw-r--  1 raphy raphy 354K set 30 19:51 build.js
-rw-rw-r--  1 raphy raphy  41K set 30 19:51 bundle.css
-rw-rw-r--  1 raphy raphy 915K set 30 19:51 bundle.js
-rw-rw-r--  1 raphy raphy 349K set 30 19:51 localization.build.js
-rw-rw-r--  1 raphy raphy  28K set 30 19:51 preload.js
```

The `bundle.css` is obtained through this script `app_S/min/scripts/buildBrowserStyles.js` :

```
const path = require('path')
const fs = require('fs')

const outFile = path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist/bundle.css')

const modules = [
  '../../../src/assets/css/base.css',
  '../../../src/assets/css/windowControls.css',
  '../../../src/assets/css/modal.css',
  '../../../src/assets/css/tabBar.css',
  '../../../src/assets/css/tabEditor.css',
  '../../../src/assets/css/taskOverlay.css',
  '../../../src/assets/css/webviews.css',
  '../../../src/assets/css/newTabPage.css',
  '../../../src/assets/css/searchbar.css',
  '../../../src/assets/css/listItem.css',
  '../../../src/assets/css/bookmarkManager.css',
  '../../../src/assets/css/findinpage.css',
  '../../../src/assets/css/downloadManager.css',
  '../../../src/assets/css/passwordManager.css',
  '../../../src/assets/css/passwordCapture.css',
  '../../../src/assets/css/passwordViewer.css',
  '../../../node_modules/dragula/dist/dragula.min.css'
]

function buildBrowserStyles () {
  /* concatenate modules */
  let output = ''
  modules.forEach(function (script) {
    output += fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, '../', script)) + '\n'
  })

  fs.writeFileSync(outFile, output, 'utf-8')
}

if (module.parent) {
  module.exports = buildBrowserStyles
} else {
  buildBrowserStyles()
}
```

which is run during the `building phase`:

in `package.json` :

```
"scripts": {
  "watch": "node ./src/app_S/min/scripts/watch.js",
  "buildMain": "node ./src/app_S/min/scripts/buildMain.js",
  "buildBrowser": "node ./src/app_S/min/scripts/buildBrowser.js",
  "buildBrowserStyles": "node ./src/app_S/min/scripts
/buildBrowserStyles.js",
  "buildPreload": "node ./src/app_S/min/scripts/buildPreload.js",
  "build": "yarn run buildMain && yarn run buildBrowser && yarn run
 buildBrowserStyles && yarn run buildPreload",
"start": "yarn run build && concurrently \"yarn run watch\" 
\"electron-forge start --inspect-electron\"",
```

In `webpack.rules.js`:

```
  {
    test: /\.css$/i,
    type: 'asset', // https://github.com/webpack-contrib/postcss-loader/issues/580#issuecomment-1130126061
    use: [
      {
        loader: "style-loader"
      },
      {
        loader:  "postcss-loader"
      },
      {
        loader: "css-loader"
      }
    ],
    //generator: {
      //outputPath: '.webpack/assets/css/'
    //},
  },
```

These are the first lines of `bundle.css`:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: ".SFNSText-Regular", "BlinkMacSystemFont", "Helvetica Neue",
    "Segoe UI", "Arial", sans-serif;
}
/* TODO figure out why the default focus color in Electron is orange */
*:focus {
  outline-color: rgb(0, 117, 255);
}
.dark-mode *:focus {
  outline-color: transparent;
}
body.mac * {
  letter-spacing: 0.4px;
}
[hidden] {
  display: none !important;
}
```

It seems to me that the files paths are correct...
What could be the causes for not applying the style and for not loading the bundle.js file? Looking forward for your kind help

Update 1)

Exchanging href with src in index_S.html file the error messages disappear but the page is still not correctly and fully rendered :

[image]

Comment: Is `<link rel=”stylesheet”` in the HTML for the `bundle.css` source file?

Comment: Hi @KamilWozniak ! I filled my question abov with details about how `bundle.css` is obtained, and about the `webpack` configuration . Thanks for helping

Comment: This issue seems to be similar to the one described in this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48248832/stylesheet-not-loaded-because-of-mime-type

Comment: @KamilWozniak I added above the first lines of `bundle.css` . I tried to remove the `*` but the problem remains

Comment: @KamilWozniak Exchanging `href` with `src` in `index_S.html` file the error messages disappear but the page is still not correctly and fully rendered, as you can see from the pic I uploaded in the Update 1) of the post above

Comment: I've created Electron Forge application similar to this one. Is it possible to see the full code of your app on a public git repository branch, because I am being unlucky in replicating the issue. renderer.js file should have a path to the css bundle and be able to include it in the html file without issues @Raphael10

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248495/discussion-between-kamil-wozniak-and-raphael10).

Comment: @KamilWozniak Ive sent you the link. What's your feedback?