# browser blocks files from express because files are not of text/html MIME type

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to run a nodejs express webserver with a static frontend, I'm using `myServer.use(express.static("public"));` to handle the GET requests made to /. the public folder contains html, js, css and some immage rescources. those all get loaded in but the browser blocks/doesn't load them because they aren't of the text/html MIME type. Is there any way I could resolve this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48666785
for people who found this post, and not the one with the answer.

Comment: you could add the short code snippet from the answer you linked. and just use the link as referrence so people can quickly use youre solution :)