# CSS and Javascript is not working in the browser

Tags: hyperlink, mime-types

p://127.0.0.1:5500/COUNTDOWN%20APP/style.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

This type of error is showing in the console panel.

i want to easily run css and js files . please help me

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48248832/stylesheet-not-loaded-because-of-mime-type is causing it, especially the second answer, which is that something may be wrong with the path to the css file and a "not found" page is returned instead, which has the type `text/html`.