# Cannot import css because of its MIME type

Tags: html, css, go

I'm working on a simple golang web-app. Trying to add some css, but facing next problem:

> "Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:8080/api/user/static/styles.css' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled"

Current project-structure

```
project-root
├── cmd
│   └── app
│       └── main.go
└── templates
    └── static
        └── styles.css
    └── register.html
```

I tried a bunch of css-file import options, but none of them worked:

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="templates/static/styles.css"/>
    <link type="text/css" href="static/styles.css">
    <link type="text/css" href="/templates/static/styles.css">
    <link type="text/css" href="./static/styles.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="templates/static/styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="templates/static/styles.css">


    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./static/styles.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./static/styles.css">
```

Also tried to add

```html
<base href="/">
```

but it didn't work for me

Tried solutions from here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48248832/stylesheet-not-loaded-because-of-mime-type](https://stackoverflow.com), it didn't work too

I'm using [github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter](https://stackoverflow.com) to navigate requests like this:

```golang
func NewRouter(userController *controller.UserController, htmlController *controller.HTMLController) *httprouter.Router {
    router := httprouter.New()

    staticHandler := http.StripPrefix("/templates/static/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("templates/static")))
    router.GET("/templates/static/*filepath", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, ps httprouter.Params) {
        staticHandler.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })

    //router.ServeFiles("/templates/static/*filepath", http.Dir("templates/static"))
    //router.ServeFiles("/static/*filepath", http.Dir("C:\\Users\\vadim\\IdeaProjects\\GoLang\\sushkof_test\\templates\\static"))

    //http.Handle("/static/", http.StripPrefix("/static/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./static/"))))
    //router.ServeFiles("/static/*filepath", http.Dir("templates/static"))

    router.GET("/api/user/register", htmlController.RegisterHandler)
    router.GET("/api/user/home", htmlController.HomeHandler)

    router.POST("/api/user/register_user", userController.Save)
    //router.ServeFiles("/templates/*filepath", http.Dir("templates"))
    return router
}
```

Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Sorry for such a huge amount of commented code, but I had to show what I already used. My brain is melted.

**UPD:**
If I change "main.go" directory to the project-root/main.go, then relative path will work, but it not working at all if "maing-go" is in "cmd/app", even if I use

```golang
router.ServeFiles("/templates/static/*filepath", http.Dir("templates/static"))
```

and

```html
<link type="text/css" href="/templates/static/styles.css">
```

Could this be an IDE (IntelliJ IDEA) issue?

Comment: @DanielA.White Nope(

Answer (score 0):

The browser reports a MIME error because the browser received a "not found" response instead of the CSS file.

Use this statement to register the file handler:

```
router.ServeFiles("/templates/static/*filepath", http.Dir("templates/static"))
```

Use this HTML to load the CSS file:

```
<link type="text/css" href="/templates/static/styles.css">
```

The application reads the file with the relative path `templates/static/styles.css`.  To resolve that relative path to the file, run the application with the [working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) set to the project root.

[Run the configured router on the playground!](https://go.dev/play/p/BPFC3vgNgA2).