# Trouble serving css and js pages with the right type using nginx setup with php-CGI

Tags: php, css, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I've been on this one all day. I have a simple website running in a Docker container with default nginx and sending php requests to another Docker container running php-CGI.

I have a series of php pages mounted in `/var/www/html/badminton/public` and a sqlite db located at `/var/www/html/badminton/server`. The owner of all these is www-data and the permissions are set to 755.

This is my file structure:

```
-badminton
  -public
    -cs
      -style.css
    -js
      -script.js
    -index.php
  -server
    -database
      -db
```

Everything regarding my db and the php files work without issues. My problem is that I can't properly serve css and js files. I get these kinds of errors:

> Refused to apply style from 'https://url/css/style.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

> Refused to execute script from 'https://url/js/script.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

I think there might be a problem with my nginx config, but I tried 50 different things and still without success. My thought is that fastcgi is serving everything, even the .css and .js files and that is why I get the wrong type 'text/html'

I also made sure that my MIME file is properly setup and that it is being included in the `nginx.conf` file.

Here is my latest version of `/etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf`:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;

        location / {
                root /var/www/html/badminton/public;
                index index.php index.html index.htm;

                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location ~ \.css$ {
                root /var/www/html/badminton/public/css;
                expires 30d;
                add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=2592000";
                try_files $uri =404;
        }

        location ~ \.js$ {
                root /var/www/html/badminton/public/js;
                expires 30d;
                add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=2592000";
                try_files $uri =404;
        }

        # Passes PHP requests to PHP-FPM container
        location ~ \.php$ {
                root /var/www/html/badminton/public;
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$; #this line
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_pass badminton-web_php-fpm_1:9000; # Replace with your PHP-FPM container name
                fastcgi_index index.php;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }

        # Logs for Nginx access and errors
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
}
```

At the moment, I get no errors in the logs of my Docker also. It only serves `/index.php` normally.

Also, if it is worth mentioning, I am using a double reverse proxy setup with the outer proxy serving to the internal Docker.

Here is my Dockerfile for the nginx Docker and the docker-compose file:

```
# Use the official NGINX image
FROM nginx:latest
# Remove default NGINX configuration
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
# Copy your custom NGINX configuration
COPY ./nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/

# Create the web root directory
RUN mkdir -p /var/www/html/badminton
RUN mkdir -p /var/www/html/badminton/public
RUN mkdir -p /var/www/html/badminton/server

# Set proper permissions for the web server user
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html \
    && chmod -R 755 /var/www/html
```

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  # PHP-FPM Service
  php-fpm:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      # Mounts the local 'app' directory to the container's Nginx root
      - ./badminton_team_auto/public:/var/www/html/badminton/public
      - ./badminton_team_auto/server:/var/www/html/badminton/server

  # NGINX Service
  nginx:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./nginx/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      # Mountlocal 'app' directory to the Nginx root
      - ./badminton_team_auto/public:/var/www/html/badminton/public
      - ./badminton_team_auto/server:/var/www/html/badminton/server
    ports:
      - "8075:80"
    depends_on:
      - php-fpm  # Depends on the PHP-FPM service
```

but these seem to work without problem

I tried changing my href="/css/style.css" to href="css/style.css"

I tried a large amount of "fix" online for my nginx config.

Trying to use `location /css {}` directly.

Trying to `add_header  Content-Type    text/css;` directly.

Tried doing this:

```
location ~* \.(js|jpg|png|css)$ {
    root /path/to/your/css/files;
    expires 30d;
}
```

and many other configurations.

Comment: What's the output of `curl -I youcsspath`?

Answer (score 0):

A quick search for your error message turns up [a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48248832/stylesheet-not-loaded-because-of-mime-type) which suggests the error is because the browser is not receiving the CSS or JS, but something like an error page, eg a 404 html page.  You can probably confirm this by just viewing your CSS URL in the browser.

With that in mind, look at the CSS/JS `location` blocks you have.  You've set a custom `root` for each - I'm not sure why you'd do that, they're part of the same site and should share the existing site `root`.  But let's say that works and is valid, I guess it would mean that requests for those files should look like `http://url/style.css` - ie with no path, because you've set the document root to the directory the file is in.

But based on your comment:

> I tried changing my href="/css/style.css" to href="css/style.css"

you're not using references like that, you're including the path again.  So nginx is probably looking for `/var/www/html/badminton/public/css/css/style.css`, which of course doesn't exist.  So you get a 404, but you've told the browser it is a style sheet, so the browser is going to complain.

Just delete the extra `root`s in your CSS/JS location blocks.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I have to say I was getting desperate and that is why I added the extra root. I tried many different ways without. Now I get why that wasn't the good strategy haha. I think my problem was with file permissions and ownership afterall, but I can't be sure because I changed strategy and ended up using the "include" feature in php to insert my styles and scripts where I needed them and avoid the error that way.. lol