# how config to show MIME Types in IIS?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, server, mime

How to show MIME Types because my IIS server didn't have MIME type like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsQlF.png).
and what must i do.
Because i need that to get image from URL then i hit the path and i got the image in other platform.
Problem is:

- There is not MIME Types in my iis server.

I have tried to turn windows features on or off and check all in internet information service(IIS) but still there is nothing MIME Types.

I have do a lot way but still can got a right way.

Comment: this may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6374419/no-mime-types-option-in-iis-7

Comment: @Must.Tek nice suggest Thanks Brooooooooo